# Импорт прайс листов из XML файла. Как быть с несовпадением категорий?

Tags: php, xml, yml

Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста, как распознать категории в XML файле.

Сайт для которого пишу импорт\экспорт прайс листов. Содержит свое дерево категорий.(И соответственно свой **category_id**). Пример ниже:

```
id 25 | Велосипеды
id 30 | parent_id 25 | Шоссейные велосипеды
```

А файл который я загружаю имеет вот такие данные:

```
<categories>
    <category id="204">Велосипеды</category>
    <category id="209" parentId="204">Шоссейные велосипеды</category>
    <category id="208" parentId="204">Горные велосипеды</category>
    <category id="279" parentId="204">Городские складные</category>
    <category id="281" parentId="204">Городские</category>
    <category id="203">Товары для спорта</category>
    <category id="226" parentId="203">Обувь</category>
    <category id="223" parentId="203">Одежда</category>
    <category id="265" parentId="203">Спортивные костюмы</category>
    <category id="267" parentId="203">Спортивная форма</category>
    <category id="215">Все для активного отдыха</category>
    <category id="216" parentId="215">Рюкзаки</category>
    <category id="254" parentId="216">Трекинговые</category>
    <category id="256" parentId="216">Городские</category>
    <category id="257" parentId="216">Экспедиционные</category>
    <category id="259" parentId="216">Штурмовые</category>
    <category id="261" parentId="216">Велосипедные</category>
    <category id="263" parentId="216">Сумки</category>
    <category id="217" parentId="215">Спальники</category>
    <category id="277" parentId="217">Демисезонные</category>
    <category id="218" parentId="215">Палатки</category>
    <category id="269" parentId="218">Трекинговые</category>
    <category id="271" parentId="218">Туристические</category>
    <category id="273" parentId="218">Кемпинговая</category>
    <category id="275" parentId="218">Аксессуары для палаток</category>
</categories>
```

Я получается должен найти категории по названию в Базе и заменить IDишники у загружаемых категорий?

А как поступить, если названия не совпадают? Добавлять товар с пустой категорией?

Та же самая картина с характеристиками товара.... У загружаемого файла они такие, а на том сайте для которого выгрузку делаю, они другие...

Как Yandex.market в таком случае работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

1. Для тех, у которых названия совпадают - искать по названию
2. Для остальных - добавлять категорию на сайт, либо предоставить пользователю возможность решать что делать с несовпадающими категориями: игонрировать; выбрать соответствие, когда есть похожая по смыслу категория; либо добавить в базу. Выбранное решение запоминать.

Answer (score 0):

Маркет просто не примет ошибочные данные.

Я бы при таких раскладах одну из таблиц использовал бы как эталон и искал по ней. Но только в случае если названия *уникальны* сами по себе. Если неуникальны, то строил бы строку с "путем" типа Водка/Кремлевская, Мясо/Колбаса/Кремлевская и искал бы также в путях.
Что не найдется, помещал бы в специальную категорию "Не найдено" - чтобы уже человек решал куда разнести.